# DEBUG [org.hornetq.jms.server] (Periodic Recovery) Returning the following list on getXAREsources:

Tags: java, performance, struts-1, hornetq, jboss-eap-6

I'm running my struts application with Jboss eap 6.1 alpha.
I noticed that there were lots of DEBUG messages in server logs, related to org.hornetq.jms.server.

I've configured my DB, JMS, HORNETQ connections in standalone.xml file in Jboss eap 6.1 alpha server.

Can anyone tell me, how to handle this, as these messages(debug) are flooding my server log files in minutes..

**Server Logs**

```
DEBUG [org.hornetq.jms.server] (Periodic Recovery) Returning the following list on getXAREsources:

 DEBUG [org.hornetq.jms.server] (Periodic Recovery) =======================================================================================

DEBUG [org.hornetq.jms.server] (Periodic Recovery) Returning the following list on getXAREsources:
13:16:53,953 DEBUG [org.hornetq.jms.server] (Periodic Recovery) server-id=fccb2b48-1d2b-11e4-830a-bdd16bd01a24, value=HornetQXAResourceWrapper [serverLocator=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=2605346d-2eae-11e4-afcb-abf5482a08bd, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null], csf=ClientSessionFactoryImpl [serverLocator=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=2605346d-2eae-11e4-afcb-abf5482a08bd, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null], connectorConfig=TransportConfiguration(name=2605346d-2eae-11e4-afcb-abf5482a08bd, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0, backupConfig=null], delegate=DelegatingSession [session=ClientSessionImpl [name=2af1bc76-2eae-11e4-afcb-abf5482a08bd, username=null, closed=false, factory = ClientSessionFactoryImpl [serverLocator=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=2605346d-2eae-11e4-afcb-abf5482a08bd, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null], connectorConfig=TransportConfiguration(name=2605346d-2eae-11e4-afcb-abf5482a08bd, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0, backupConfig=null], metaData=()]@56bd6e3d], xaRecoveryConfigs=[XARecoveryConfig [transportConfiguration = [TransportConfiguration(name=2605346d-2eae-11e4-afcb-abf5482a08bd, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0], discoveryConfiguration = null, username=null, password=null]], instance=1798001212]
13:16:53,953 DEBUG [org.hornetq.jms.server] (Periodic Recovery) 

=======================================================================================

13:16:53,953 DEBUG [org.hornetq.jms.server] (Periodic Recovery) looking for recover at DelegatingSession [session=ClientSessionImpl [name=2af1bc76-2eae-11e4-afcb-abf5482a08bd, username=null, closed=false, factory = ClientSessionFactoryImpl [serverLocator=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=2605346d-2eae-11e4-afcb-abf5482a08bd, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null], connectorConfig=TransportConfiguration(name=2605346d-2eae-11e4-afcb-abf5482a08bd, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0, backupConfig=null], metaData=()]@56bd6e3d] configuration [XARecoveryConfig [transportConfiguration = [TransportConfiguration(name=2605346d-2eae-11e4-afcb-abf5482a08bd, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0], discoveryConfiguration = null, username=null, password=null]]
13:16:53,953 DEBUG [org.hornetq.jms.server] (Periodic Recovery) looking for recover at DelegatingSession [session=ClientSessionImpl [name=2af1bc76-2eae-11e4-afcb-abf5482a08bd, username=null, closed=false, factory = ClientSessionFactoryImpl [serverLocator=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=2605346d-2eae-11e4-afcb-abf5482a08bd, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null], connectorConfig=TransportConfiguration(name=2605346d-2eae-11e4-afcb-abf5482a08bd, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0, backupConfig=null], metaData=()]@56bd6e3d] configuration [XARecoveryConfig [transportConfiguration = [TransportConfiguration(name=2605346d-2eae-11e4-afcb-abf5482a08bd, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0], discoveryConfiguration = null, username=null, password=null]]
13:16:58,344 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.session] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1409833018344 sessioncount 0
13:16:58,344 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.session] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
13:16:58,344 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.session] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1409833018344 sessioncount 0
13:16:58,344 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.session] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
13:16:58,344 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.session] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1409833018344 sessioncount 0
13:16:58,344 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.session] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your jboss-log4j.xml file change the appropriate category to a lower level such as INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL.

This file is normally located in ${JBOSS_HOME}/server/${SERVER}/conf/jboss-log4j.xml.

Restart the server

NOTE: It seems that your default logger is probably set at DEBUG in this file